# TYPO3 Extbase: Create record from external source AND/OR manually

Tags: typo3, extbase

I want to develop a TYPO3 extension with a data model and a corresponding backend form. This **backend form should be auto-filled** by entering some sort of globally unique ID and fetching the data **from an external source** based on that ID. If the external source does not return a result or that globally unique ID does not exist, the **data can still be added manually.**

Is there a way to do that? Or do I have to resort to just storing the GUID locally and fetch the data in the frontend?

For clarification: My usecase are **scientific publications** and their **[DOI](https://www.doi.org/)** as a globally unique ID.

*Note about my knowledge: I have developed extensions with their own data models, corresponding backend forms, and frontend output. I have also used generic external data (not specific data based on an ID) in such backend forms, fetched via curl. But I have no idea where to start for what I described above.*

For a better understanding, consider the following model and workflow:

### Data model, simplified

For simplification, let’s assume the model just has the following three properties:

- `guid` – globally unique ID
- `title` – the title of the dataset, e.g. publication
- `authors` – the author(s) of the dataset, e.g. publication

### Workflow to create a new record

Now, when I **add a new record in the TYPO3 backend,**

- I want to show an empty field for each of these properties in the “Create” form
- after entering the `guid` I want my extension to send a request to an external data source using this `guid`, and fill `title` and `authors` automatically from the result of that request
- if the request is empty or I have no `guid` available, I can add the information manually
- the whole record will be stored in the TYPO3 database table for my model

### Nice-to-have addition

Consider, the external data stored for the `guid` can change, it would be nice to be able to fetch the external data again via the Edit form of an already locally stored record. However, this will not be necessary very often.

Comment: @David: Thank you! If you found that and could give me a hint, that would be brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [*External Import* package](https://packagist.org/packages/cobweb/external_import) for this. The related documentation describes very well how you could integrate your external data source for importing records into TYPO3.

To cover your described case "keep additional records not present in the external data source" you may need to add `delete` to [disabledOperations](https://docs.typo3.org/p/cobweb/external_import/main/en-us/Administration/GeneralTca/Index.html#disabledoperations). But first you need to clarify what should happen, if the external data source actually provides data for a record which did only exist locally so far. Should the external data be ignored? Should your local data be overwritten by the external data? Again you can use the configuration to skip records in this case.

Comment: Thank you, @mathias-brodala, I will check this out. However, I’d still prefer to do that without an additional T3 extension, but maybe this will help me get an idea.